# Notifications in Android 9 while the app is closed

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-9.0-pie

How do you make notifications keep showing up while an app is closed? I have code kind of like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = database.child(username);

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
//some stuff here
}
```

Here, I give the user notifications whenever they get a new message or something, which works fine while they have the app open. How do I make this listener keep listening and notifying, even after the user closes the app? I've read online about making a Service or Intent yada blada, but none of that seems to work with Android 8+... any advice? I also read something about making a foreground service, but the app crashed when I tried that because I don't know anything about those.

Comment: You should look into push notifications (for instance, Firebase Cloud Messaging).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Foreground Service or WorkManager, which is part of Android Jetpack. WorkManager from the docs:

> WorkManager is an API that makes it easy to schedule deferrable,
> asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or
> the device restarts. The WorkManager API is a suitable and recommended
> replacement for all previous Android background scheduling APIs,
> including FirebaseJobDispatcher, GcmNetworkManager, and Job Scheduler.
> WorkManager incorporates the features of its predecessors in a modern,
> consistent API that works back to API level 14 while also being
> conscious of battery life.

Check out more at the: [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

If you are working with firebase, you should check out FCM too, at [firebase's official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging?hl=es-419)